# Google Calendar feed api deleted events

Tags: google-calendar-api, gdata, gdata-api

I'm syncing the Google Calendar with my application (I store events in a database). When an event is updated I can easily find the last updates by sorting the event feed on the 'updated' order. 
However, if an event is removed / deleted, how can I track this update from the feed?

Comment: Do you mean if someone deletes the event from the Google side or from your database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add `showdeleted=true` to your query feed and then check for `EventStatus.CANCELED` on retrieved entries.

[Check](http://groups.google.com/group/google-calendar-help-dataapi/browse_thread/thread/32d38dbe2732d2d0/099887310bbf4252?lnk=gst&q=deleted+sync) this thread for further information.

Comment: I can confirm that this is stil the case in 2016. I created then deleted an event and used google API explorer to view the result. It just turns "cancelled". All other details of the event is still shown.

Answer (score -1):

I did exactly the thing you want to do (see this post: http://code.pui.ch/2009/12/29/fetch-publicly-available-google-calendar-data-with-python/):

I have a database with events imported from Google and events that can be edited from an admin interface (Django).
All events I import from Google I mark in the database with a flag.
When importing from Google I first delete all events in the future and then `INSERT` all events I retrieve from Google.

To circumvent that the events get new ids with every import I did some hacking (python. It's *very* hackish, but it solved my case):

```
    guid_int = "".join(re.findall('[0-9]*', str(vevent.get('UID'))))
    guid_int = guid_int[:9]
```

guid_int is what I use as the primary key in the database..